# I can not allocate memory in an array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int crp(int mtrs[],int size)
{
    int a=1;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        a*=mtrs[i];
    }

    return a;
}

int main()
{
    int k,size;
    int **mtrs;

    printf("enter the size of the matrix:");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    mtrs=(int**)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));

    if( mtrs == NULL )
        printf( "Yetersiz bellek!" );

    printf("enter the input numbers of matrix:");

    for(k=0;k<size;k++)
    {
        mtrs[k] =(int*) malloc( size* sizeof(int) );
        if( mtrs[k] == NULL )
            printf( "not enough memory!" );
    }
    for(k=0;k<size;k++) 
    {
        scanf("%d",&mtrs[k]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    for(k=0;k<size;k++){
        printf("%d ",mtrs[k]);
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Elemanlar carpimi %d dir.",crp(mtrs[k],size));

    return 0;
}
```

I get the problem of access violation reading location 0xFDFDFD.

it stucks at the location of  a*=mtrs[i];.. The program's aim is to multiplication of the entered numbers

I am not sure if I am using the malloc in a correct way.

Comment: You `scanf` into `mtrs[k]`, and you also print `mtrs[k]`. Now think a little while, what *is* `mtrs[k]`?

Comment: Which value has `k` in this line `printf("Elemanlar carpimi %d dir.",crp(mtrs[k],size));`?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/dzcB3RgQ627QqcCUqJU6Lj   it works fine in this way, however if you enter more than 6 input numbers, it does not work. so I wanted to use malloc to resolve this problem...

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet is invalid

```
for(k=0;k<size;k++) 
{

    scanf("%d",&mtrs[k]);
               &&&&&&&&
}
```

You should write for example

```
int m;
//...

for(k=0;k<size;k++) 
{
    for ( m = 0; m < size; m++ )        
    {
        scanf("%d", &mtrs[k][m]);
    }
}
```

The same is valid for this loop

```
for(k=0;k<size;k++){


    printf("%d ",mtrs[k]);

}
```

It should look like

```
for(k=0;k<size;k++) 
{
    for ( m = 0; m < size; m++ )        
    {
        printf("%d ",mtrs[k][m]);
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

The function should be defined like

```
long long int crp( int * mtrs[],int size)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    long long int a=1;
    int i, j;
    ^^^^^^^^^


    for(i=0;i<size;++i)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < size; j++ )
        {
            a*=mtrs[i];
        }
    }

    return a;
}
```

And the result of the function should be outputted like

```
printf("Elemanlar carpimi %lld dir.",crp(mtrs,size));
                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: `scanf("%d",&mtrs[k]);  &&&&&&&&` is not valid, remove `&&&&&&&&` from code or edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I do not fully understand what is your code point, but you have various mistakes and logic problems with it.

1. `printf("%d ",mtrs[k]);` and `scanf("%d",&mtrs[k]);` expect `int` but you passed `*int` (aka `int[]`), you probably need to insert/read values using 2 nested `for` loops.
2. `printf("Elemanlar carpimi %d dir.",crp(mtrs[k],size));` last cycle is `for(k=0;k<size;k++)`, according to it `k = size`, so `mtrs[k]` is out of bounds, which cause application crash.

Comment: paste.ofcode.org/dzcB3RgQ627QqcCUqJU6Lj it works fine in this way, however if you enter more than 6 input numbers, it does not work. so I wanted to use malloc to resolve this problem...